# How does Tatum die?

Tags: scream

In the film *Scream* (1996) how exactly is Tatum killed?

Is her skull crushed in the garage door, or is her neck broken?

When she hits the top of the door frame you can clearly see the side of her skull is instantly caved in by the impact, but later on her body is found hanging in the door by her neck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

She is killed instantly when her head is flattened and her neck is snapped. Her body is found hanging in the door by her neck because her neck is snapped.

[Wikia](http://scream.wikia.com/wiki/Tatum_Riley)

[image]

[image]